# How to extend a partition using Gparted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have only 17GB on my ext4 partition so I'm trying to extend it using GParted, I have already created the unallocated space and moved it where my ext4 partition is, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAX9M.png), I booted Ubuntu from my USB as well, but when I try to Resize/Move ext4 it's like those 40GB are just not available, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDU8D.png). What can I do? I found in forums I have to move ext4 next to the unallocated space but I can't see any option for this, how could I do that? Do you think I should be using another method for extending the partition? In that case, what do you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't extend to the left in the partition layout, only to the right, and only to free space immediately adjacent to the partition to be resized. The screenshot shows the free space (a) is to the left and (b) has two other partitions before the one you want to resize (which is why you don't get the option to move), so it's doubly unusable.

Comment: You can try making a new partition in the empty space and the copying the old partition to the new one (`dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/dev/sda<whatever>`)